# Convert string into arithmetic operators

Tags: sql, firebird, arithmetic-expressions

I have an equation stored in a table and want my SQL to return the calculated value.

e.g

```
Select replace (c.equation, 'x', 121) 
  from config c where key= 2
```

The above returns (8.5-(121-20)/100) . I need the calculated value ,i.e 7.49

I tried the following but not working :

```
Select cast(replace (g.equation, 'x', 121) as double precision) 
  from config c where key= 2
```

Any idea please?

Comment: you may try `EXECUTE STATEMENT` and `EXECUTE BLOCK` commands or you may try writing the calculator as UDF DLL, but all in all this does not look as a task suited for RDBMS, it would hardly seem reliable and optimal... http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-execblock.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by @Arioch you have to use **[EXECUTE STATEMENT](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-psql-execstat.html)**. Than just put equation in following procedure CALCULATE

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE calculate (equation VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS (result VARCHAR(10))
AS
begin
  EXECUTE STATEMENT ('SELECT ' || :EQUATION || ' FROM rdb$database')
  INTO :result;

  suspend;
end
```

Comment: until someone would put SQL Injection as a formula. www.bobby-tables.com

Comment: @Arioch'The Luckily `execute statement` only allows a single statement, so that reduces the risk of other statements getting executed, but that this is indeed not a very safe idea.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel for example a single `EXECUTE BLOCK` statement. I also used those two portals to transcend from Dynamic SQL to Procedure SQL and back here on SO once. Though I do not remember at once why on Earth had I once to devise this voodooesque scheme.

Comment: @Arioch'The true, but you can't put an `execute block` within a `select` (as far as I'm aware), reducing the attack surface with the code as shown.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel okay, not an attack indeed, but any crash due to erroneous unchecked input, syntax errors, etc. Other than "proof of concept" for some school lesson I see little reasonable application for such a calculator.